# Sometimes my website, which has fb sdk is being redirected to strange url

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Sometimes user in my website is being redirected to strange url like this: https://connect.facebook.net/help/contact.php?show_form=post_problem.

I checked and the site has embed fb sdk like this:

```
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/signals/config/<key>?v=2.8.12&amp;r=stable" async=""></script>

<script async="" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js"></script>

<script>
!function(b,e,f,g,a,c,d){b.fbq||(a=b.fbq=function(){a.callMethod?a.callMethod.apply(a,arguments):a.queue.push(arguments)},b._fbq||(b._fbq=a),a.push=a,a.loaded=!0,a.version="2.0",a.queue=[],c=e.createElement(f),c.async=!0,c.src=g,d=e.getElementsByTagName(f)[0],d.parentNode.insertBefore(c,d))}(window,document,"script","https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js");fbq("init","my id");fbq("set","agent","tmgoogletagmanager","some value");fbq("track","PageView");
</script>
```

Does anyone have the same problem ? I still can not figure out where it triggers the redirect...

Comment: My guess would be that this is actually supposed to redirect to https://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=post_problem I have no idea what that first script you are embedding there is though, so can’t tell you anything more about this, than that Facebook for example redirects users to such a form if an app traps then in a redirect to the login dialog, although the already declined, or similar situations.

Comment: thanks for your info, I'll investigate more.

Comment: I've also faced this issue at the moment. Does anybody have a solution?